# SQL query extract max row

Tags: sql

my sql query

```
select *
  from (
            select *
              from (
                     select b.course_code       currentc
                          , b.pre_reqcoursecode prec
                       from (
                               select course_code
                                    , pre_reqcoursecode
                                 from adss_PreReqCourses
                            ) a
                       join adss_PreReqCourses b
                         on a.course_code=b.course_code
                      where b.course_code='EE218'
                   ) F
                join adss_CoursesResult w
                  on F.prec=w.course_code
               where w.GradePoint='B'
        ) J 
     join adss_CoursesResult I
       on J.currentc=I.course_code
 group by I.GradePoint
        ;
```

output:

```
GradePoint  Predicted
C+           24628
C            22372
B-           18424
```

now how to get the gradepoint with highest predicted count??

Comment: Why not wrap it in `SELECT * FROM ( .. ) AS baseview ORDER BY Predicted DESC LIMIT 1` ?

Comment: after order by how to get first row?

Comment: Via `LIMIT 1` - that's why I wrote it ...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177651/extract-from-table

Comment: visual studio 2012 is not recognizing limit 1 :S

Comment: If you are talking of Microsoft SQL, you need to drop the `LIMIT 1` and instead use `SELECT TOP 1 FROM` ... I assumed MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for SQL Server (and since you said that you are using Visual Studio 2012, it is likely):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (/*Your Query Here*/) A
ORDER BY Predicted DESC
```

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaannks alottt :) greatt

Answer (score 0):

change line

```
select *
```

to

```
select top 1 *
```

and add one last line

```
order by Predicted desc
```